Recursive template inside inner @for in Angular 17
I'm trying to create a recursive template an ran into a problem.
My template:
<ng-template #recursiveGroups let-groups>
  @for (group of groups; track group; let i = $index) {
      <!-- Some stuff are shown -->
      @for (subGroup of group.subGroups; track subGroup;  let j = $index) {
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveGroups; context:{$implicit: data[i].subGroups[j]}"></ng-container>
        <!-- ALSO, SEPARATLY, TRIED: -->
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveGroups; context:{$implicit: subGroup}"></ng-container>
        <!-- OR: -->
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveGroups; context:{groups: subGroup}"></ng-container>
      }
  }
 </ng-template>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveGroups; context:{$implicit: data}"></ng-container>

My data looks like:
data: [
  {
    ...,
    children: [
      {
        ...
      }
    ],
    subGroups: [
      {
        ...,
        children: [
          {
            ...
          }
        ],
        subGroups: [
          {
            ...,
          }
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
  ...
]

Using context:{groups: <*>} shows only the top most level.
Using context:{@implicit: <*>} shows only the top most level and also raises error:
core.mjs:6531 ERROR TypeError: newCollection[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
What am I missing here?
Thanks.

you just need to add ngIf condition befor second loop group.subGroups

Would be great if you could provide sample data. You provide data which is an object in <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveGroups; context:{$implicit: data}"></ng-container>, the data is not iterable.

@DaksheshBaldaniya can you elaborate? ngif with what condition? What is it for?

@YongShun Sorry, you're right, I forgot to write "data" as an array of objects. Fixed. Anyway, I can see the first layer consisted of children and the meta-data of  each sub group, but again, only in the first layer.

Your recursiveGroups template expects an array, hence I don't see you need a nested @for for the subGroups. The template can be reused for the subGroups iteration.
Changes:

Remove the nested @for.

Provide the group.subGroups to the context for the nested <ng-container>.


<ng-template #recursiveGroups let-groups>
  @for (group of groups; track group; let i = $index) {
    
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveGroups; context:{ $implicit: group.subGroups }"></ng-container>
  }
</ng-template>

Demo @ StackBlitz

You are running the forLoop at the top of the template, so there is no need for more for loops in recursion. All you need to do is to ensure the input for the recursive template remains as a array, then it will render correctly:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <ng-template #recursiveGroups let-groups>
      @for (group of groups; track group; let i = $index) {
        {{group.id}}
        <hr/>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveGroups; context:{$implicit: group.children}"></ng-container>
        <hr/>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveGroups; context:{$implicit: group.subGroups}"></ng-container>
      }
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveGroups; context:{$implicit: data}"></ng-container>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  data: any = [
    {
      id: 1,
      children: [
        {
          id: 2,
        },
      ],
      subGroups: [
        {
          id: 3,
          children: [
            {
              id: 4,
            },
          ],
          subGroups: [
            {
              id: 5,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you very much! Would accept that answer as well, but I can only accept one.
